# Having trouble with Bootstrap css

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am building ASP.NET MVC web site from pure   HTML/ CSS  template.
Everything looks fine except  CSS (bootstrap css)
here is the example how the original template looks like
http://livspartner.azurewebsites.net/DesignTemplate/ 
and here is live web site.
http://livspartner.azurewebsites.net/

I see that the CSS consist of boostrap.css, bootstrapTheme.css and style.css.
Can someone point me out what am I missing here and why the HTML elements are shifted in the live web app?

Comment: Your fonts are not loading for one...

Answer (score 1):

I have examined the source of both websites. Whenever getting a pre-built theme of a website, always make sure that you add all the assets needed. After examining your source I have come to a conclusion that you are missing chosen.min.css in your ASP.NET MVC Website.

Thanks.